# Tag alias: BLE / bluetooth-low-energy

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can we alias the far less often used [ble](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ble) to [bluetooth-low-energy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-low-energy)?

From its 26 usages, [ble](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ble) is used 10 times in conjunction with [bluetooth-low-energy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-low-energy) already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a reasonable request ... done!